# LastOrDefault() not supported on IQueryable {document}{}.LastOrDefault()is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

```
IQueryable<Patients> patients = db.Patients; 
    
patients = patients.Where(x => x.Status.LastOrDefault().Status != Status.Imported);
```

On the 1st line I have a IQueryable data. (1,000+ data)

On the 2nd line The "Status" is a List of object. I wanted to get the last list of Status and have a condition.

But this gives me an error *"{document}{Status}.LastOrDefault().Status is not supported."*

Is there any workaround to implement this? I cannot perform IEnumerable because it will load too slow.

I'm using MongoDB for my database.

Comment: Does this thread help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476289/last-method-not-working-on-iqueryable-object

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to access an Array inside a IQueryable which is the Status. And performing LastOrDefault() gives me an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last and LastOrDefault not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Try "unwrapping" `LastOrDefault`:

```cs
patients = patients.Where(x => (x.Status.Length == 0 ? default : x.Status[x.Status.Length - 1]).Status != Status.Imported);
```